# Modify data with SPARQL Update

Tags: sql-update, sparql

I am using SPARQL Update to perform what is the usual SQL update query. What is easy in SQL makes SPARQL look a bit impractical.

So I am running a parametrised query:

```
DELETE { 
          ?id ex:name ?oldname .
          ?id ex:description ?olddesc .
       }
INSERT {  
          ?id ex:name "My new name" .
          ?id ex:description "My new description" .
}
WHERE { 
          ?id ex:name ?oldname .
}
```

What I want is to modify the old values for the new ones. I suppose I have to delete all values and insert the new ones. My first issue is that I don't know or I suppose I don't care what the old values are, so I just want to modify whatever value was there for the new one (exactly as in a SQL query). However I don't know how to specify this. I see no point at all in having to create additional SELECT queries to retrieve all values, store them in memory and execute the update (seems like a lot of burden and inefficiency, especially with large queries). My query above simply inserts, but doesn't delete anything because `oldname` and `olddesc` are not bound.

The `id` is bound in the parametrised query. I suppose the `WHERE` clause could be empty (`WHERE {}`), since I don't need it.

Is there a simple way to do this?

---

**EDIT**

System.out.println query:

```
DELETE { ?id ex:name ?oldname .
        ?id rdfs:label ?oldlabel .
        ?id ex:description ?olddesc .
       } INSERT { ?id ex:name ?name .
                 ?id rdfs:label ?name .
                 ?id ex:description ?desc .
                }
       WHERE { OPTIONAL { ?id ex:name ?oldname }
              OPTIONAL { ?id rdfs:label ?oldlabel }
              OPTIONAL { ?id ex:description ?olddesc }
             }
# Overrides by the API: 
# PARAMETERS ( ?name ?id ?desc ) {
# "NewName"
# <http://example.com/test#doc64>
# "FaldosX"
# }
```

Comment: Where do you bind values for `?name` and `desc`?

Comment: It is parametrised on the Java program, via a method parameter(), just before executing the query. The parameters are correctly set as I can see from the print ("Overrides by the API")

Comment: The only thing is (as perhaps you are thinking) that the .parameter() does not override the parameters in all clauses DELETE, INSERT and WHERE....

Comment: Verified - parameter() didn't override parameters in DELETE and INSERT clauses, despite of what the "overrides by the API" said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SPARQL is different conceptually from SQL because it work with a different kind of data - RDF graph vs. table-based relational data.  Therefore you need to think of SPARQL in terms of graph pattern matching.  It's not a matter of one being easier than another, but of having to understand different data specification languages. (XPath over XML is yet another example - you need to think in terms of paths in trees, not relational tables or graphs.)

I'm not sure what you mean by "...because `oldname` and `olddesc` are not bound." `?oldname` is bound in the `WHERE` clause of your query.  So the solutions is very close:

```
DELETE { 
   ?id ex:name ?oldname .
   ?id ex:description ?olddesc .
 }
INSERT {  
   ?id ex:name "My new name" .
   ?id ex:description "My new description" .
}
WHERE { 
   ?id ex:name ?oldname .
   OPTIONAL {
      ?id ex:description ?olddesc .
   }
}
```

I added the `OPTIONAL` in case not all bindings of `?id` have a `ex:description`.

Again, the principle here is similar to SQL - you need to specify the data you want to replace.  That is done by querying for existing data, deleting it, and specifying the new data.

Note the syntax is flexible enough to also replace specific data.  Suppose there are multiple values for `ex:description`.  Then the following would replace the specified value and leave others as-is.

```
DELETE {
   ?id ex:description "One old value" .
 }
INSERT {
   ?id ex:description "My new description" .
}
WHERE { 
   ?id ex:description "One old value" .
}
```

Note the `WHERE` clause is still necessary because you need to find bindings for `?id`.

Comment: In the where clause you mean ex:description, right?

Comment: I am using the query with the OPTIONAL clause as you suggested, apparently it executes fine from the Java program but the data get deleted and not inserted. I have been doing tests for hours but cannot see what can be wrong. Does this make any sense?

Comment: @user1156544 scott's query is correct AFAICT, and executing it _should_ delete old values and insert new ones. What SPARQL engine are you using?

Comment: I am using Java + Stardog. What is funny is that data get deleted indeed. I will update the printed query in my question